# How do I disable text shadows in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, colors, css

I normally turn of colors and read the web with a gray background. Some sites use text shadows, for example [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), which results in white borders around letters that make the text hard to read.

Technically this is implemented by a CSS property called `text-shadow`.

Is there a way to disable text shadows?  I've looked into `about:config` but didn't find anything.

Or is it a Firefox bug? After all, I told it not to display colors.

I guess the same applies to the `text-outline` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a user style sheet with

```
* { text-shadow: none !important; }
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks.  The hardest part was finding the right `userContent.css` file to put it into. I actually already had one from 2004 that I had completely forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox 4, you can do this by adding:

```
.tabbrowser-tab { text-shadow: none !important; }
```

to the userChrome.css file

Comment: How does that differ from Joey's answer above?

Comment: sorry had not seen it.. realised it later after i had posted. was in a hurry.

Comment: The difference is that this applies to the tabs in the Firefox UI, while I need it for the web page.  Hence the `*` in the correct answer, and it goes in file `userContent.css` instead of `userChrome.css`.